# Часть речи слова "утром"

Tags: морфология

Я проснулся утром. Я проснулся ранним утром. Одинакова ли морфологическая характеристика слова "утром"?  В первом случае это наречие. А во втором? С одной стороны, есть зависимое прилагательное, прилагательные зависят от существительных. С другой стороны, ну никак не могу задать вопрос падежный, даже с натяжкой (чем я проснулся? - невозможно). Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> В первом случае это наречие.

**Да.**

> А во втором?

**Существительное в творительном падеже**, выполняет функцию обстоятельства времени, в связи с чем приобретает наречный компонент в семантике. Но более сильным признаком является наличие определения при слове ***утром***, что не позволяет считать ***утром*** в данном предложении наречием. **СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОЕ.**

> С другой стороны, ну никак не могу задать вопрос падежный...

Ну так к обстоятельству-то и не задают падежные вопросы.

Comment: Всё-таки я никак не могу понять "глубинные причины" такой метаморфозы. Тут наречие, там существительное... Ну совсем же одинаково построенные фразы. Что-то тут не так...

Comment: Всё так, причина - переход других частей речи в наречия в определенных условиях (при отсутствии определений). Чаще всего это существительные в творительном падеже с временным значением или со значением образа действия. Ср.: выехали утром, встретились весной, «временами накрапывало, шли шагом — выехали ранним утром, ранней весной, покончено с тяжелыми временами, шли бодрым шагом.В первых сочетаниях выделенные слова являются наречиями,они примыкают к глаголам, а в последующих — существительными, т.к. они согласовываются с прилагательными, наречия же вступают только в отношения примыкания

Answer (score 1):

Если рассматривать слово *утро* как морфологическую единицу, то можно сказать, что это слово имеет два значения:

— форма творительного падежа существительного *утро* (обозначает предмет, явление);
— наречие (обозначает временной признак действия).

Когда рассматриваем слово в контексте предложения или словосочетания как синтаксическую единицу, то руководствуемся структурой связи слова с другими словами предложения.

Так в предложении "Я проснулся утром" слово *утром*:
 — синтаксически связано со сказуемым;
 — отвечает на вопрос "когда?" и является обстоятельством (связь - примыкание);
 — может иметь при себе зависимое слово *рано* (связь — примыкание).

В этом случае обстоятельство выражено **наречием** *утром*.

А в предложении "Я проснулся ранним утром" слово *утром* имеет при себе зависимое слово *ранним*, которое согласуется с ним в форме творительного падежа единственного числа среднего рода (связь — согласование).

Следовательно, в данном предложении обстоятельство времени *утром* выражено **именем существительным**.